# Останавливается анимация когда вкладка со страницей переключена anime.js

Tags: javascript, anime.js

простейшая анимация, например,

```
anime({
  targets: '.element',
  rotate: 5000,
  duration: 5000,
  easing: 'cubicBezier(0.15, 0.15, 0, 1)'
});
```

Так когда она запускается если вкладку в браузере переключить то она встает на паузу и только когда мы возвращаемся продолжает проигрываться, возможно ли чтобы анимация проигрывалась независимо от того активна ли вкладка или нет

Comment: Возможно, если делать анимацию на чистом css, то может быть... Хотя навряд ли :) Нет, никак нельзя так сделать. А зачем вам анимация на не активной вкладке?

Comment: Потому что у меня такой случай что если вернутся на вкладку то анимация уже должна быть закончена, например ее длительность 10с то через 10с уже другое там действие, а я возвращаюсь, а у меня все анимирует

Comment: подсчет положения должен быть с учетом времени, прошедшего с начала открытия вкладки, т.е. с расчетом на переменную частоту кадров

Comment: Ничего с этим не поделаешь. Браузер приостанавливает активность на неактивной вкладке, включаю setInterval, requestAnimationFrame и  анимацию. Можете использовать gif картинку, если вам это подходит :)